# How to replace NA values sbased on a known value at a specific year?

Tags: r

I am looking for a function which calculates an NA value based on a known value at a specific year, and which can be run across different groups seperately.

Practice dataset:

```
   value  year location
   <int> <int>    <int>
 1    NA  1990       11
 2    NA  1991       11
 3     3  1992       11
 4    NA  1993       11
 5    NA  1994       11
 6    NA  1990       12
 7     2  1991       12
 8    NA  1992       12
 9    NA  1993       12
10    NA  1994       12
```

```
structure(list(value = c(NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 
NA), year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1990L, 1991L, 
1992L, 1993L, 1994L), location = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    location = 11:12, .rows = list(1:5, 6:10)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

What I would like to do first is group by `location`. For now I used dplyr to do this.

```
df <- df %>% group_by(location)
```

Now, for every group, I want to replace the NA values based on a known value at a specific  year. The values change with +1 per year. The desired output would thus be:

```
   value year location
1      1 1990       11
2      2 1991       11
3      3 1992       11
4      4 1993       11
5      5 1994       11
6      1 1990       12
7      2 1991       12
8      3 1992       12
9      4 1993       12
10     5 1994       12
```

My real dataset has thousands of locations, so I am looking for a function which can be ran across the whole dataset at once. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two approaches with `base R` for data frame `df`:

- **Solution 1** (using `ave()`)

```
res <- within(df,value <- ave(year,location,FUN = function(x) x-min(x)+1 ))
```

- **Solution 2** (using `split()`)

```
res <- Reduce(rbind,
       Map(function(k) dfs[[k]] <- within(dfs[[k]], value <- year -min(year)+1),
           seq_along(dfs<-split(df,df$location))))
```

giving

```
>  res
   value year location
1      1 1990       11
2      2 1991       11
3      3 1992       11
4      4 1993       11
5      5 1994       11
6      1 1990       12
7      2 1991       12
8      3 1992       12
9      4 1993       12
10     5 1994       12
11     8 1997       12
```

**DATA** (borrow from @sindri_baldur)

```
df <- data.frame(
  value = c(NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1997),
  location = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L)
)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. Works very nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(location) %>% 
  mutate(value = year - min(year) + 1L)
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  value = c(NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1997),
  location = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L)
)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the quick reply :) In this practice dataset it would work, but in my real dataset I have years which are skipping (for example 1990-1991-2000). Sorry that I did not include that in the practice dataset. In that case the 1:n() function would not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any library just do `df$value = 1:nrow(df)`, it will give the follow dataframe:

`value  year location
   <int> <int>    <int>
 1     1  1990       11
 2     2  1991       11
 3     3  1992       11
 4     4  1993       11
 5     5  1994       11
 6     1  1990       12
 7     2  1991       12
 8     3  1992       12
 9     4  1993       12
10     5  1994       12`

Comment: Thanks for your help! In the bigger dataset however I have skipping years (for example 1990-1992-2000). Sorry I did not specify that before in the practice dataset. Could you give a suggestion on how to handle this?

Comment: I don't know if I understood well, but you can know the number of years that you have in the year column with length(unique(df$year)), then you can use 1:length(unique(df$year)). Did it help?

Comment: I now used the mutate function posted by sindri_baldur. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `row_number()` after grouping

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(location) %>%
   arrange(location, year) %>%
   mutate(value = row_number())
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   location [2]
#   value  year location
#   <int> <int>    <int>
# 1     1  1990       11
# 2     2  1991       11
# 3     3  1992       11
# 4     4  1993       11
# 5     5  1994       11
# 6     1  1990       12
# 7     2  1991       12
# 8     3  1992       12
# 9     4  1993       12
#10     5  1994       12
```

---

Or with `coalesce`

```
df %>%
   group_by(location) %>%
   arrange(location, year) %>%
   mutate(value = coalesce(row_number(), value))
```